# How to sort {relations}_count when {relations}_count not in the database tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm doing the Laravel task and I want to sort a table which is related to another table.
I read the document here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models
My code:

```
$addonCategories = AddonCategory::withCount('addons')->sortable()->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->with('addons')->paginate(20);
return view('admin.addonCategories', array(
            'addonCategories' => $addonCategories,
        ));
```

AddonCategory Controller:

```
class AddonCategory extends Model
{
    use Sortable;
    protected $casts = ['addons_count' => 'integer'];
    public $sortable = ['name', 'type', 'addons_count', 'created_at'];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function addons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Addon');
    }
}
```

addonCategories.blade.php:

```
<th>@sortablelink('addons_count', __('storeDashboard.acpTableNOA'))</th>
```

And when I used sortable, the error occurs

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'addons_count' in 'order clause'
```

I think it is because there is no addons_count in the database table. So how to sort with {relations}_count like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it appears you are using the library: https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable

The `$sortable` attribute in your `AddonCategory` matches the array elements, with the column names of the table.
Hence you are receiving the error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'addons_count' in 'order clause'`

Given that the `addons_count` column is absent in the MySQL table `addon_category` and is added by laravel as an attribute, you'll need to implement `Aliasing`, which is specified in the [library's documentation](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable#aliasing)

Your final model will be as:

```
class AddonCategory extends Model
{
    use Sortable;
    protected $casts = ['addons_count' => 'integer'];
    public $sortable = ['name', 'type', 'created_at'];
    public $sortableAs = ['addons_count'];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class);
    }

    public function addons()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Addon');
    }
}
```

The rest of your implementation is good.

[Here's a link to a github issue which relates to yours.](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable/issues/49)